# Обьясните что за ветки гит на сервере?

Tags: git

Я читаю туториал по гит и пытаюсь разобраться, вроде все понял. Вот следую рекомендациям "удачная модель ветвления" , как правильно это работает :

Так

На сервере 2 ветки `master` и `develop` и когда мне нужно сделать новую фичу я делаю себе локально ветку `feature` от удаленой ветки `develop` в ней работаю и потом делаю ей пуш обратно в удаленую ветку `develop`

Или так

У меня копии этих веток. То есть 2 ветки `master` и `develop` на сервере и 2 ветки `master` и `develop` локально когда нужна новая фича, то я делаю себе локально ветку `feature` работаю в ней, потом делаю ей мердж в локальную ветку `develop` и уже локальную ветку `develop` пушу в удаленую ветку `develop` ?

Я просто не могу до конца сообразить обязательно ли ветки на сервере и локально являются точной копией друг друга или я могу иметь ветки на сервере делать от них ветки локально и пушить их обратно на сервер когда заканчиваю с ними?

Comment: Судя по всему вам и сервер то не особо нужен.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian судя по чему?

Comment: По вопросу. В смысле, что раз нет отдельного человека ответственного за релиз, то сервер у вас больше как бекап похоже работает.

Comment: Ну и у git другая философия - все что у вас на компе - это такой же полноправный репозиторий как и на сервере или у сотоварища. Можете как угодно ветвить, и дальше либо сливать с другими репозитариями, либо не сливать (полная свобода действий).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я использую его только для сохранения проекта, чтоб хранить проект не только локально, а и удалено, чтоб в случае чего у меня была копия... Ну и для понимания его работы вот тренируюсь и стараюсь следовать принципу `удачная модель ветвления`

Comment: Если только как копия - то можно время от времени пушить разом все (ветки, теги) в удаленный (ые) репозитарий.

Comment: При наличии master/develop часто возникает необходимость ещё в ветке hot-fixes, которая ответвляется от master, правится, и сливается назад, на случай каких-то срочных фиксов, когда develop ушел далеко от master.

Comment: Вот вам еще полезная ссылка как раз по той модели ветвления, которую вы описываете: http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html

Comment: Я тут тоже (в очередной раз) поигрался с `git` и опять пришел к выводу, что для одиночной работы старый добрый `tar` в сочетании с парой файлов `ChangeLog` и  `MyNotes` для меня удобнее (может и для Вас тоже).

Comment: @avp да но я не знаком с  tar и + я хочу наработать опыт работы с гит чтоб потом было проще ориентироваться в командной работе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас вопросы появляются из-за двух моментов:

- Существует много удачных практик разработки в git (и вы [ссылаетесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/) только на одну из них) - поэтому вам всё время отвечают на ваши вопросы "и так тоже бывает можно, гит весьма гибок". Как команда договорится - так и будет. Пробуйте разные методики, не утыкайтесь в одну -- команды вам могут встретиться разные в жизни.
- Вы работаете в одиночку, учитесь основам гит - и просто не можете порой сформулировать вопросы, которые у вас и не возникли бы при командной работе. Чесслово, для одиночной работы можно настолько много всего упростить и это будет намного быстрее в работе (чем меньше команда разработчиков -- тем меньше накладные расходы на бюрократию, на нетворкинг и т.п.) В первой же команде вы бы быстро поняли, что и как принято, как работает. После третьей команды можете уже четвёртой рекомендовать поменять методику на основе своего опыта, возможно примут если окажется удобнее.

Но давайте попробуем ответить строго на поставленные вопросы:

> обязательно ли ветки на сервере и локально являются точной копией друг
>   друга или я могу иметь ветки на сервере делать от них ветки локально и
>   пушить их обратно на сервер когда заканчиваю с ними

Ответ1, тривиальный. "Как договоритесь с командой". Можете вообще выкинуть половину описанной методики, если сам с собой договоритесь.

Ответ2, формальный. "В методике, которую вы ходите освоить есть значительная свобода для неважных ветвей (взяли себе фичу из трекера, работаете с ней в отдельной ветке как вам удобно. с вас разве потребуют соблюдать определённые принципы наименования веток, чтобы никто не путался - скажем, по номеру тикета) и строгие правила по работе с основными ветками, особенно - по выкладыванию релиза". Правила определяет команда, они в статье опущены, так как некритичны.

Вас такие ответы устраивают или что-то ещё непонятно? Суть вот какая: проекты все разные, команды и методологии -- тоже, поэтому на ваши несколько сумбурные вопросы сложно дать ответы не в духе "всяко бывает". Да, существуют best practice, их нужно знать (ваша статья -- лишь одна из рекомендуемыех best practice), к ним стремятся но в каждом конкретном проекте/команде могут быть выкинуты некоторые детали.

Comment: Да я тут еще немного почитал + ваш ответ и вроде опять все стало понятно)) Вроде пока все работает)) Просто эти ветки меня путают, там одни тут другие и было не понятно, то ли они должны соответствовать друг другу с двух сторон то ли я могу не держать их копий... Но сейчас для себя остановился на том, что нужно создать мастер и дев удалено и от них делать локальные ветки фичи в них работать и отправлять обратно на сервер. Сервер мне нужен чтоб хранить там проект на всякий случай если вдруг что... Работаю я сам так что нужно просто для себя понять что как сделать))

Comment: Я только не могу разобраться, как можно создать ветку на сервере? Я делаю команду `git checkout -b develop` и создается ветка дев, но она создается локально... А как ее создать на сервере? Мне нужно чтоб на сервере был мастер и дев... Сейчас у меня только мастер на сервере

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko дык `git push -u origin develop`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Если любытны подробности, то посмотрите [вот этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543752/) сегодня только задали.