# Как отправить изменения из текущей ветки в новую ветку в удалённом репозитории?

Tags: git, git-push

Если выполнить команду `git branch -a` то она выводит вот такое

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
* develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

2 ветки локальные и 2 на сервере... Локально `master` и `develop` , и теперь если я хочу сделать пуш на сервер, то мне обязательно нужно его делать в мастер... Но эта ветка у меня для релизов...

Как создать на сервере ветку дев?

ПРАВКА

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://gitlab.com/alekseytimoshchenko/NewTimeZone.git
  Push  URL: https://gitlab.com/alekseytimoshchenko/NewTimeZone.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, вывод `git remote show origin`

Comment: `git checkout develop && git push -u origin develop`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил

Comment: @KoVadim не до конца понимаю, что делает ваша команда, переключается на ветку(а если я уже на ней?) , и делает пуш в дев на сервере( но там нет этой ветки...) ... Можете обьснить?

Comment: вначале переключаемся. Если уже там, то можно не делать, но ничего страшного не будет. Вторая команда "отправляет ветку на сервер с привязкой". Если ее там нет, то она будет создана.

Comment: Да точно, вроде получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> $ git remote show origin
> ...
>   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
>     master merges with remote master
>   Local ref configured for 'git push':
>     master pushes to master (up to date)
> ```

здесь видно, что для команды `git pull` (без параметров) сконфигурирована только локальная ветка `master` (будут забираться обновления из удалённой ветки `master`). аналогично и для `git push` (без параметров) — только обновления из локальной ветки `master` будут отправляться в удалённый репозиторий (в удалённую ветку `master`).

---

локальную ветку можно сконфигурировать на отправку изменений в любую ветку удалённого репозитория (при вызове `git push` без параметров в этой ветке).

проще всего это сделать, однократно передав команде `git push` опцию `-u` (`--set-upstream`). естественно, надо указать и имя репозитория и ветку в нём, к которой текущая ветка будет «привязана».

для вашего конкретного случая:

1. сделайте ветку `develop` текущей:

   ```
   $ git checkout develop
   ```
2. отправьте изменения из неё, одновременно указав «привязку» к удалённой ветке `develop` в репозитории `origin` (приведён и пример вывода):

   ```
   $ git push -u origin develop
   Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To url-репозитория
    * [new branch]      develop -> develop
   Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
   ```

   последняя строчка как раз и сообщает о том, что локальная ветка `develop` «связана» с удалённой веткой `develop` (в репозитории `origin`).

---

теперь команда:

```
$ git remote show origin
```

покажет чуть больше информации про «привязки»:

```
...
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop merges with remote develop
    master  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop pushes to develop (up to date)
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
```

и выполняемая в дальнейшем в ветке `develop` команда `git push` (без параметров) отправит изменения именно в удалённую ветку `develop`.

---

### к слову

разово отправить изменения из любой локальной ветки в (почти) любую ветку в удалённом репозитории (и не осуществляя никаких «привязок») можно так:

```
$ git push репозиторий локальная_ветка:удалённая_ветка
```

например, для вашего случая:

```
$ git push origin develop:develop
```

если ветка с указанным именем не существует в удалённом репозитории, она будет создана. а если существует, то, в принципе, команда может завершиться с ошибкой — если «влить» изменения из локальной ветки в удалённую не получится. но это уже совсем другая история.